# How to add text data from URL into an existing JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So yeah, working on a project where I'm taking data from a text file on a web server and adding it to an array to display on an HTML document.

The text file on the web server, I'll just call `values.txt`, looks like this:

```
value b
value c
value d
value e
value f
```

This is the code of my current attempt:

```
const newArray = ["value a"];

const fileUrl = *url of values.txt*;
    fetch(fileUrl)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then((text) => {
            const array2 = text.split("\n");

            for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
            {
                newArray.push(array2[i]);
            }
        })

document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += ("<br>Array test: " + newArray[1]);
```

In theory, `newArray[1]` should return `value b`, instead it returns as undefined.

Comment: You need to put the `innerHTML` assignment inside the `.then()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the asynchronous nature of the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Move your code that update the DOM inside `then` block:

```
.then((text) => {
    const array2 = text.split("\n");

    for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
    {
        newArray.push(array2[i]);
    }
    //Update the DOM here
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += ("<br>Array test: " + newArray[1]);
});
```